# Keepass causes immediate Linux logout when using auto-type

Tags: logout, keyboard-event, keepassxc

Today I had to restart my computer after a total freeze of Linux. After that I now have the problem that **KeepassXC 2.7.1 leads to a immediate logout of my Linux system as soon as I try to use the auto-type functionality**. It doesn't matter if it should type a user name, a password or both. I also tried different credentials - the problem stays the same.
In the weeks before I never had this problem, using this function very often.
=> **What could be the root cause for that problem?**

- Another odd thing is that KeePass asks now for a confirmation if it should auto-type into the window which was active before. It never posed this question before. I know this is a setting but I never changed this setting.
- A second restart of Linux didn't solve this problem. After the restart I get the information that there is no space on partition `/boot`. But there are 82MB free space on this partition.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Michael, there's at least three questions in one. Could you edit this question post down to one clear question, please?

Comment: I tried to describe my problem more precisely. I hope I made it clear enough.